# text of the native(Admob) button is under pressure

Tags: android, admob, native-ads, google-native-ads

I implemented the small native ad on the main activity and I do not why the text of the native button is under pressure.
In addition, I changed nothing in the Native template.

My Problem with Native Button
![My Problem with Native Button][1]

[1

```js
AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(view.getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.native_history))
                .forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                        NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
                                NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build();
                        TemplateView template = view.findViewById(R.id.my_template);
                        template.setStyles(styles);
                        template.setNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd);
                    }
                })
                .build();

        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.HistoryFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_view_history_fragment_history"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.ads.nativetemplates.TemplateView
        android:id="@+id/my_template"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:gnt_template_type="@layout/gnt_small_template_view" />
</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_history_fragment_history"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVik0.png

Comment: post your implementation in your question

Comment: Put some code with your questions. That will make it easier to help.

Comment: i edited the question and put code in there